# Unable to hide certain feature types in Google Maps

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm using the Google Maps API Styled Map Wizard (http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/styledmaps/wizard/index.html?utm_medium=twitter) to customize the look of a map I want to use which is zoomed in up to street level (zoom: 16). I basically want to get rid of all labels, text or icons. I'm getting there around 95% but still certain labels, namely: names of squares, remain.

Until now I haven't found a way to also hide these labels. Although I suspect a bug in the customization features of Google Maps (or this tool) I'd like to ask if anyone experienced the same issue? Does someone have any tips on how to approach or maybe even solve this?

Below a screenshot that illustrates the issue.
Any tips are welcome. Thanks!

[image]

```
    function initialize() {

        var mapStyles = [ 
            { 
                "featureType": "administrative", 
                "stylers": [ { "visibility": "off" } ] 
            },{ 
                "featureType": "road", 
                "elementType": "labels", 
                "stylers": [ { "visibility": "off" } ] 
            },{ 
                "featureType": "road", 
                "elementType": "geometry.stroke", 
                "stylers": [ { "visibility": "off" } ] 
            },{ 
                "featureType": "road", 
                "elementType": "geometry.fill", 
                "stylers": [ 
                    { "visibility": "on" }, 
                    { "color": "#ffffff" }
                ] 
            },{ 
                "featureType": "transit", 
                "stylers": [ { "visibility": "off" } ] 
            },{ 
                "featureType": "poi.attraction", 
                "stylers": [ { "visibility": "off" } ] 
            },{ 
                "featureType": "poi.business", 
                "stylers": [ { "visibility": "off" } ] 
            },{ 
                "featureType": "poi.government", 
                "stylers": [ { "visibility": "off" } ] 
            },{ 
                "featureType": "poi.medical", 
                "stylers": [ { "visibility": "off" } ] 
            },{ 
                "featureType": "poi.park", 
                "elementType": "labels", 
                "stylers": [ { "visibility": "off" } ]                  
            },{ 
                "featureType": "poi.place_of_worship", 
                "stylers": [ { "visibility": "off" } ] 
            },{ 
                "featureType": "poi.school", 
                "stylers": [ { "visibility": "off" } ] 
            },{ 
                "featureType": "poi.sports_complex", 
                "stylers": [ { "visibility": "off" } ] 
            },{ 
                "featureType": "landscape.man_made", 
                "stylers": [ 
                    { "visibility": "on" }, 
                    { "color": "#fce8f0" } 
                ] 
            },{ 
                "featureType": "landscape.natural", 
                "elementType": "labels", 
                "stylers": [ { "visibility": "off" } ] 
            },{ 
                "featureType": "landscape.natural", 
                "elementType": "geometry", 
                "stylers": [ 
                    { "color": "#fce8f0" }, 
                    { "visibility": "on" } 
                ] 
            },{ 
                "featureType": "water", 
                "elementType": "labels", 
                "stylers": [ { "visibility": "off" } ] },
            { } 
        ];  

        var mapOptions = {
            center: { lat: 52.519772, lng: 13.399022},
            zoom: 16,
            scrollwheel: false,
            mapTypeControl: false,
            panControl: false,
            zoomControl: false,
            scaleControl: false,
            streetViewControl: false,
            styles: mapStyles
        };

        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),mapOptions);

    }
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that exhibits the issue.

Comment: I've added my tested code as an example. Will that do?

Comment: Also found this issue as a bug request for Google Maps. For solution see accepted answer below. https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=5572

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to get rid of all text labels, turn them off alltogether:

```
var mapStyles = [{
    featureType: "all",
    elementType: "labels.text",
    stylers: [{
        visibility: "off"
    }]
}];
```

If you want to get rid of all labels, `elementType: "labels"` will do for both `labels.text` and `labels.icon`, etc. The same applies for feature types.

```
var mapStyles = [{
    featureType: "all",
    elementType: "labels",
    stylers: [{
        visibility: "off"
    }]
}];
```

<kbd>[JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/upsidown/35cnt1e6/)</kbd>

From the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MapTypeStyleFeatureType): *Note however that parent features may include some additional features that are not included in one of their child feature types.*

Comment: Thanks Mr, I was looking way too specific I guess. (looking for a specific featureType for this) Turning off all labels obviously helps :)

Comment: @tvgemert I don’t think that it is too specific. It is a problem which is really annoying, and I don’t see any reason, why these labels aren't turned off, when you turn off the road labels, because they are road labels. At least in Germany.

But thank you @MrUpsidown!

Comment: The reason is as noted above: *Note however that parent features may include some additional features that are not included in one of their child feature types.* If you feel like Google should change anything about that, then create a [feature request](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/entry).